# hiding the browser's address bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, address-bar

My client requires that the address bar of the browser get hidden as soon he accesses the project .
I'm trying to figure out a way to trigger a full screen event on load . But apparently this can't be done since requestfullscreen can only be called with user event (click , keypressed...)

here's my code :

```
   function goFs(id) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id);

    if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        element.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
        element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
    }
}
//goFs('test');
```

Is there any hack to simulate a full screenmode on  webapplication load ?

Answer (score 4):

This is impossible. Browsers are highly resistent to efforts to conceal the URL they are visiting from users (since this would greatly aid efforts to perform phishing attacks).

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found for doing that is to use a window popup in your first page (index.hxtml for example)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function popupAppli(){
    parent.opener = top;
    params = "menubar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,left=0,height=701,width=1016,top=0,scrollbars=no,status=no,resizable=yes";
    loc="(another xhtml page)";
    popsApp = window.open(loc,"My application",params);
    if(parent.location != popsApp.location){
        parent.close();
    }           
</script>
```

Then, you call the function on body onload

```
<body onload="popupAppli();"></body>
```

It's not really full screen but I didn't find another solution